# React input currency mask

Tags: reactjs, input-mask

I have a currency input(euro), and i used the react input masking to correct the numbers while the user is typing, but how can i make the user able to type ','?He can type numbers and '.' only.

```
    CurrencyInput
                        id="input-example"
                        name="input-name"
                        defaultValue={formatedResult}
                        decimalsLimit={2}
                        decimalSeparator="," 
                        groupSeparator="."
                        onValueChange={(value, name) => console.log(value, name)}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
      <CurrencyInput
        prefix="$"
        id="input-example"
        name="input-name"
        decimalsLimit="2"
        onValueChange={(value, name) => console.log(value, name)}
      />
```

Comment: The problem is that the user can not type the ','

Comment: @NewReactDeveloper Why do you want to add the separator (,) manually? It will add auto according to currency.